# MYSQL Select and Insert

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, insert

Why wont this work! I have been pulling my hair out for days trying to get this to work

```
 $query2 = "SELECT * FROM temporders WHERE order_id=$id";
 $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
 $osupplierid = $row['order_supplierid'];
 $odescription = $row['order_description'];
 $odate = $row['order_date'];
 $oquoteid = $row['order_quoteid'];
 $odetailid = $row['order_detailid'];
 $otype = $row['order_type'];
 $osupplierquote = $row['order_supplierquote'];
 $osupplierquotecost = $row['order_supplierquotecost']; 

 $query = "INSERT INTO orders (order_supplierid, order_description, order_date, order_quoteid, order_detailid, order_type, order_supplierquote, order_supplierquotecost )
             VALUES ($osupplierid, $odescription, $odate, $oquoteid, $odetailid, $otype, $osupplierquote, $osupplierquotecost )";
```

It doesn't seem to fin the values for row as nothing gets input, as if i Replace them with dummy values it works.

Please help! Its Xmas eve and I want to finish work early.

Ian

Comment: We are not a free debugging service.

Comment: what is the error getting you

Comment: What error do u getting?

Comment: And it would appear you could do that with one query (insert into table(fileds...) Select fields... From Temporders Where order_id = $id  and prove the query in mysql or some other tool.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some of the parameters in your INSERT Query are String, and you must use single quotes, even if it's PHP Variables.

I added quotes for the fields which seem to be String-type, check this and try again !

```
$query = "INSERT INTO orders (order_supplierid, order_description, order_date, order_quoteid, order_detailid, order_type, order_supplierquote, order_supplierquotecost )
         VALUES ($osupplierid, '$odescription', '$odate', $oquoteid, $odetailid, '$otype',     '$osupplierquote', $osupplierquotecost )";
```

To go a litthe further, it's important to notice that the PHP mysql_* functions are depreciated, and that you should use PDO or the mysqli_* functions.

I recommand this guide for a quick overlook of PDO : http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-Data-Object/PDO-Tutorial-P842.html

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
 $query = "INSERT INTO orders (order_supplierid, order_description, order_date, order_quoteid, order_detailid, order_type, order_supplierquote, order_supplierquotecost )
             VALUES ('$osupplierid', '$odescription', '$odate', '$oquoteid', '$odetailid', '$otype', '$osupplierquote, $osupplierquotecost ')";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $query2 = "INSERT INTO orders (order_supplierid, order_description, order_date, order_quoteid, order_detailid, order_type, order_supplierquote, order_supplierquotecost ) SELECT order_supplierid, order_description, order_date, order_quoteid, order_detailid, order_type, order_supplierquote, order_supplierquotecost FROM temporders WHERE order_id=$id";
 $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
```